# Maximum value of a function with condition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

Hello everybody I have a question about this :

> Let a function $f$ with domain $]0,+\infty[$ and codomain $]0,+\infty[$ and twice differentiable with the following inequality :
>   $$f'+f''\geq f^2>0$$

Furthermore we now this about $f$ and this condition :

1)$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$

2)$f(x)$ is convex for all $x>0$ or $f'<0$ for all $x>0$

3)$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f(x)=\infty$

4)If we make this substitution $f(x)=ln(g'(e^{-x}))$ so we have (if we apply the inequality) :
$$e^{-2x}[\frac{g'''(e^{-x})}{g'(e^{-x})}-\frac{g''(e^{-x})^2}{g'(e^{-x})^2}]\geq ln(g'(e^{-x}))^2>0$$

So there is a link with the [Schwarzian derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative)

5)We can find $\alpha$ such as we have :
 $$\frac{ln(-e^{-\alpha x }+1)}{-\alpha x}\leq f_{\alpha}(x)$$

So now my question is: what's the maximal value of $f(n)$?

Second Edit :Geometrically speaking If you take the [osculating circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle) of a function $f(x)$ what's the maximum value that can be taken by the osculating circle of minimum radius ?

Finally I give you some examples of functions wich verify the inequality :
$$f(x)=\frac{ln(-e^{-\alpha x }+1)}{-\alpha x}$$

for all $\alpha\geq 1$
$$f(x)=ln(|\frac{e^{x^2}-1}{e^{x^2}+1}|)^2$$
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{x^2}$$

Edit : Furthermore we know that we have under the initial inequality $f'(x)^2\leq f(x)f''(x)$ for all $x>0$ so this [paper](https://jyx.jyu.fi/dspace/bitstream/handle/123456789/52426/bariczetal035451801502303b.pdf?sequence=1) could be useful .

Third edit : I found a 'maximal' function (maybe there exists an another that's all the question ) wich is : $$M(x)=\frac{3 e^{-x}(x^2+2)}{x^2}+7e^{-2x}+3e^{-3x}$$

So for the moment I can't find better than this : $f(1)\leq M(1)$

If we put the following substitution $f(x)=g''(1-e^{-x})$ we get :

$$e^{-2x}g^{(iv)}(1-e^{-x})\geq g''(1-e^{-x})^2$$

So [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X9996434X) is interesting if we assume that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}f(x)=l$ where $l$ is a real positive number .

We get :

$$g^{(iv)}(0)\geq g''(0)^2$$ wich corresponds to $d=1$ in the paper .

Thanks a lot .

Comment: I precise that $x$ is real .

Comment: I found a partial answer in [it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954845/bezier-curvature-extrema/1956264#1956264)

Comment: I don't think f exists. I haven't proved it but here goes.  from your first and third condition we can see that the function has to asymptotically decrease. there is the problem.in your second condition you say your function always has to decrease everywhere. however because the sum of the derivative and the second derivative have to be strictly larger than zero, somewhere the derivative has to  become positive (since the second derivative has to be positive in the entire domain), which means the function has to increase. However the function cannot increase again because then f is not convex.

Comment: I am not 100% sure this reasoning holds btw so proceed with caution but intuitively it seems that this function cannot exist

Comment: I think there is a way with radial function see [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-08/S0002-9939-01-05839-7/S0002-9939-01-05839-7.pdf)

Comment: Furthermore see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775443/is-pi-the-best-constant-in-this-inequality)